# i:nill="true" appears in response

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a model -

```cs
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public double? Salary { get; set; }
}
```

and a `LINQ` method syntax like -

```cs
public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees()
{
    using (var DbCon = new OfficeEntities())
    {
        var result = DbCon.Employee.Select(x => new EmployeeModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name
            //Salary = x.Salary,
            //Designation = x.Designation
        })
        .ToList();
            
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have commented out salary and designation but even though it prints with
key : salary and for value `i:null="true"` why
result comes like this

```xml
<EmployeeModel>
    <Designation i:nil="true"/>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Sulochana </Name>
    <Salary i:nil="true"/>
</EmployeeModel>
```

Even though commented/removed the parameters in the query, why it is appearing in the result. Kindly help

Comment: Whilst this is by design, you can take steps to remove fields that are null during serialization if you really want to. It's beyond the scope here, but it is a common requirement omit nulls (nils) in API contracts, there is a lot on content on this on SO alone

Comment: the field don't have null values

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't include those properties in the projection.
This has a special meaning for the client to interpret, it's not that these fields have a null value, these fields we're not included in the projection, so their values are indeterminate.

If the client has requesting a projection with `$select=Id,Name` then these fields would not have been included at all, but because the client is *expecting* all the fields this is how the API expresses to the client that the fields we're deliberately omitted, but to satisfy the return contract the fields must be provided in some form.

---

This answer is assuming OP is writing an OData service, but the same concept applies with Linq to Entities in general. If the Linq expression is projecting into a model type, but not including certain fields, then those fields will have an uninitialized value on the model instances that are projected out.

Comment: How to write a code in this case to omit those columns

Comment: Is this an OData scenario? The method return type is the overarching issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an `EmployeeModel` object in the `Select` projection. Hence, `Salary` and `Designation` are being initialized with their default values, even though you didn't set values for them. Then after serializing all properties are present in the result.

If you are expecting only `Id` and `Name` in the output/result, then define a type in that shape -

```cs
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and create an object of that type in the projection -

```cs
var result = DbCon.Employee.Select(x => new EmployeeInfo()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Sir, from model I can not remove the salary and designation properties, like this kind of solution even I too though in the beginning but Model properties are fixed.  because for some method i need two property and for some i need three etc., it is not wise to create a classes like that. is there any other solution

Comment: @Jaya I'm not suggesting to modify your model. `EmployeeInfo` is a new class and its only purpose is to hold the result.

Comment: I understood sir.  but if my class is having 20 properties and each controller method required 2 properties. then i should create 10 classes.  and how is it possible sir. Their might be some possible solution.

Comment: @Jaya APIs require results in various shapes and model classes are not always a better suit to represent them. Creating/Using classes (DTO models) to hold/represent the result is a very common case with APIs. I don't understand why you think it is `impossible`.

Comment: Ok Sir. I am new to this API industry.  I have many tables and joins and though it will increase the complexity of classes. so thought like that.  I will create a sub class, which a method actually requires and give only those in response.  Thank you

Comment: @Jaya You might also want to take a look at AutoMapper ( https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) and its `ProjectTo<T>()` method. It can do the projection operation (operations in the `Select()` method) for you, which will make your life a lot easier with models that have a lot of properties. You can do the query simply as `var result = Mapper.ProjectTo<EmployeeInfo>(DbCon.Employee).ToList();`.

Comment: sir, i used this and resolved the issue                                      DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class EmployeeModel
{
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] 
    public string Designation { get; set; }
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] 
    public double? Salary { get; set; }
}